# Woocommerce Product upsell

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product

my question is very simple...

I want to hide some products but still be able to "Upsell" them.

now, if I hide any product form shop page, it will not show in Upsell.

Can I find a solution to this?

Why? :  we have same products but different colours that I do not wish to repeat but I want to show them on the Upsell instead. and no, I do not want to use Product Variation, nor Groupe products, nor categories, nor tags...  none of this stuff, it's not a pleasant visual experience, but if I can upsell my hidden variations, that would solve a lot of problems...

Do I really have to figure out how to remove the shop page and create a new custom page and sort product by product manually for them to exist and be able to upsell?

is there any smart guy or girl who can see this through ?

P.S.  I'm using the Dante Template